# Displaying mySQL images determined by category and/or tag

Tags: php, mysql, image, tags, gallery

I'm relatively new to PHP/mySQL and I'm trying to develop a portfolio of my images. I have already set up an admin control panel where I can upload a photo from my hard-drive and store data about the image (including it's path) into a database. What I'm wondering is, could anyone point me to a tutorial or information on how to set up a category and/or tagging mechanism, so I can assign multiple tags/categories for an image, and have them be displayed based on that.

For example, I have an image: npr_001_day.jpg. This is a 'mountain' picture and also a 'winter' picture. I want to enable it so when I click on a link for 'mountains' it will display. I also want it to display when i click on the 'winter' category too.

I've been looking on the web for a while and have been able to find anything usable.

Thanks ahead for any help!
Tre

Comment: It doesn't look like it has tags, but there's a quite indepth tutorial over on Sitepoint for making a complete image gallery with categories - [http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-gallery-system-minutes](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-gallery-system-minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what's called a "many to many" relationship in relational database lingo.  I'm assuming you have an IMAGE table where you image data goes.  You'll need to add a CATEGORY table to store your categories and a CATEGORY_IMAGE table to store relationships between images and categories.

CATEGORY_IMAGE would have two columns, one for the ID of an image, and one for the ID of an associated category.  Here's a pretty good overview of what you need - http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the speedy reply. I was just reading a posting about this. I will give it a go and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck!  It took me a while to wrap my head around relational modeling.  This is a pretty good book on basic relational stuff, if you can get your hands on a copy - http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Database-Design-Novice-Professional/product-reviews/1590597699/ref=dp_top_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I read a pretty good tutorial over at: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/php/relational_db_design.htm. Which seemed to help paint a good picture for me.